# Does Rails automagically figures out the primary in a MongoDB replica set if only has one host configured?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker, replicaset

Here's the scenario:

**Node1:**

- Rails docker container, monogid.yml **only has one host**: mongo:27017
- Mongo docker container (named 'mongo'), configured as a Replica set with mongo in Node2 and an arbiter.

**Node2:**

- Rails docker container, monogid.yml **only has one host**: mongo:27017
- Mongo docker container (named 'mongo'), configured as a Replica set with mongo in Node1 and an arbiter.

I'know the `mongoid` config should have a list of hosts in the replica set rather than only one,

But when testing the above I can see that if a go to the Web in **Node2**, the mongo in **Node1** is the one getting the load, even when that host is not configured in Node2 config.

So, Can I leave the configuration of mongoid on both nodes just like that?

Is it really necessary to use the list of host in the config or would the driver in Rails figure it out on its own?

Let me know if more details would be helpful or if the explanation isn't clear.

Update: the load from the web is both reads and writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most drivers will call db.isMaster() upon connecting which will return a set of nodes in the replica set. This allows the driver to discover other nodes and reconnect to the primary. Normally you should list all known nodes in case the one you seed is down temporarily. Since you have configured a replica set you must already have an addressed for all the nodes, so why not just list it in the connection URI? 
Hint: you can use an alias in /etc/hosts if you can't set up a proper DNS reference to all hosts

Comment: Thanks Nic, I will probably do that and add all the hosts available, but I was curious about the behavior.